# htaccess NC flag not working with RewriteCond

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following setup:

user types in domain.com/weeklyad

file named weeklyAd.php in the root of my directory

and the following in my .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ "index.php?loc=$1" [L]
```

I expect the first set of checks to match, but it is falling through to the second check. Any ideas why the NC flag is not working?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the NC flag works, it applies to a case insensitive pattern match, and doesn't apply to the `-f` and `-d` checks (which aren't regex/pattern related).

Something you can try is loading mod_speling and do `CheckSpelling On` to make the URL-file mapping case insensitive, but I'm honestly not sure if that applies to the `-f` check. You may need to just route everything into a php script and have the php script figure it out.